# C# - maintaing interface after updates on ef .edmx file

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on a MVC project where I'm working towards updating the code base so that we can begin using MS Test to test our code base. My approach is use a Repository pattern for our interaction with databases and using Dependency Injection to help develop mock objects in our testing project.

Our MVC project uses a database first approach for updating the `.edmx` file. We use VS to generate the code when we adding\updating tables and other db objects. 
When updates are made to the `.edmx` file, then this updates my project's `DBContext` class. My `DBContext` class implements an interface that had I created which stores all of the tables `(DBSet<TableName>)` that I use in my project.

Every time I update my `.edmx` file with a new table, VS removes the reference to my interface.

I want to know how can I stop VS from removing my interface reference in my `DBContext` class. Every time I update my `.edmx` file VS removes my reference to my interface file and when I run my MS test project I get errors because my `DBContext` object no longer implements the interface that I created.

Comment: Don't put your code into the DBContext Class.  Create a new class for the interface.

Comment: Look at my answer please.  Do not forget to mark as answered if it fixes your issue.  I have done this kind of changes many times in the past.

Comment: As @jdweng states. Don't put any extra logic inside the DbContext. The extra logic/methods should be implemented using a separate service class that has the DbContext injected in to it.

Comment: @phuzi for adding code you can also use a partial class. I updated my answer with information on how to use partial classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**:

You can change your T4 Template.

Find your EDMX file.  Nested within that file there is a file called **NameOfYourModel.Context.tt** and inside that file there is a line similar to this one:

`<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext`

That line of code is the one that generates your Context.  So next to DbContext add ", Interface Name" so the end result will be like this:

`<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext, IMyInterface`

Save the file.  Now every time you regenerate the code your Context will have that interface in it's declaration.  You can make further modifications to the generated context in this file.

**Option 2:**

The other option is to create a partial class in a separate file with the same declaration as your Context.  And put your custom code inside that file.  Partial class files get merged into a single class at compile time. They have to be in the same project and under the same namespace.

For more information on [Partial Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)

Comment: How will this work to actually implement the interface?

Comment: You said that "VS removes my reference to my interface file".... So this will make so that it will not remove the interface reference from your dbcontext. Furthermore... If you want inside that same file you can make more modifications to the way your context gets generated. Cheers

Comment: @phuzi I also added another option.  If you want you can also make a nother file with a partial class and that file will not get overwritten.